# rails devise after sign up not allowing access sign_in and sign_up page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I am using rails4 and latest devise.
It seems after I signed up an user from devise, I could not access

```
/users/sign_in and
/users/sign_up
```

pages (all pages being redirected to root )

I have to clean up browser cookies to access these two pagae. Is there some setting I can turn this thing off. I was trying to testing I need to access these pages very often.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once `current_user` is set via Devise, the `RegistrationsController` actions of `sign_in` and `sign_up` are no longer available – those actions can only be accessed by non-logged in users.

In both the default [`RegistrationsController`](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/app/controllers/devise/registrations_controller.rb) and [`SessionsController`](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/app/controllers/devise/sessions_controller.rb), you'll see the following directive:

```
prepend_before_filter :require_no_authentication, :only => [ :new, :create ]
```

Basically, this prevents access to the `new` and `create` actions of both controllers by users who are already logged in. This makes sense: if a user is already logged in, why would he/she need to sign in or sign up?

If you'd like to override this default behavior, you can try overriding these controllers with the following:

```
`prepend_before_filter :require_no_authentication`, :only => :none
```

This declares that no actions should `require_no_authentication` as a precursor to access to the action in  question.

Comment: But it was just sign up,not sign in yet and not confirmed yet

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Can you clarify?

Comment: So once a user signed up devise defaultly makes a user signed in ?

Comment: Yes – when a user completes the sign up process via Devise, they are automatically signed in. A glimpse at the Devise [RegistrationsController](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/app/controllers/devise/registrations_controller.rb) reveals what happens after a new user resource is successfully saved. Does this make sense?

Comment: I modified your code to make its compatible with my `registrations_controller.rb`. I need to use `before_action :require_no_authentication, only: [:none]`, to allow signed in user to access sign up page.